# Endless loop with read/update database record from and to excel by using vba in visio

Tags: vba, events, visio

Hello guys from stackoverflow,

i’m currently create a tool with Excel and Visio to gather all the data about our it infrastructure that our it-department has a big picture of our it-assets. It’s pretty cool to collect all data with excel and draw a network map of our assets with visio shapes. But one thing is really important for us in case of this tool, we want a bidirectional connection between them to be able to do changes in excel (and visio recognizes) and we want to change shape-data in visio (and write it down to excel). In visio you can manually update the excel-file by clicking "update record in database" and load data from excel by choosing "update shape-data" in the context-menu of a shape. In the shape-sheet of a shape i have a row e.g. User. StartMakro_IP in the section user-defined Cells. In this field i have a formula =CALLTHIS("update_item")+DEPENDSON(Prop.IP). This formula calls the update_item method (located in the modul „mdl_admin“) to write down changes to my excel-file:

```
Public Sub update_item(shp As Visio.Shape)
If shp.CellExists("User.ODBCConnection", Visio.visExistsAnywhere) <> 0 Then
'Loop thru to check if shape has refresh action
    If shp.SectionExists(Visio.visSectionAction, Visio.visExistsAnywhere) <> 0 Then
        For iRow = 0 To shp.RowCount(Visio.visSectionAction) - 1
            If shp.CellsSRC(Visio.visSectionAction, iRow, Visio.visActionAction).Formula = "RUNADDON(""DBU"")" Then
                'Force the cell formula to run
                    shp.CellsSRC(Visio.visSectionAction, iRow, Visio.visActionAction).Trigger
                    Exit For
            End If
        Next iRow
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

To be able to load latest changes out of excel we call the method selectionchanged everytime a shape is selected. This method is located in ThisDocument and implemented as follows:

```
Dim WithEvents MyWindow As Visio.Window

Private Sub Document_RunModeEntered(ByVal doc As IVDocument)
    Set MyWindow = ActiveWindow
End Sub

Private Sub MyWindow_SelectionChanged(ByVal Window As IVWindow)
    If Window.Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Window.Selection(1).CellExists("User.ODBCConnection", Visio.visExistsAnywhere) <> 0 Then
        'Loop thru to check if shape has refresh action
            If Window.Selection(1).SectionExists(Visio.visSectionAction, Visio.visExistsAnywhere) <> 0 Then
                For iRow = 0 To Window.Selection(1).RowCount(Visio.visSectionAction) - 1
                    If Window.Selection(1).CellsSRC(Visio.visSectionAction, iRow, Visio.visActionAction).Formula = "RUNADDON(""DBR"")" Then
                        'Force the cell formula to run
                        Window.Selection(1).CellsSRC(Visio.visSectionAction, iRow, Visio.visActionAction).Trigger
                        'MsgBox Window.Selection(1).Name
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next iRow
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In my mind the matter is, that the currently implemented methods triggers themselves (database update / read data from database)  and so an endless loop will appear. In fact Visio crashes at this time and the application will unfortunately closes down.

Does anyone know another method to write changed shape-data from current visio-shape to excel and simultaneously read new data from excel and update shape-data of the current selected visio-shape?

Any help is highly appreciated. If possible please provide any tiny example codes to catch that exception, because i'm not really familiar with events in visio.

Best regards

Joerg

Answer (score 0):

The BackSync addin from here (visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=6086.msg24731#msg24731) solve all the problems and reduces a lot of pain!